# Nether portals exiting into a different location

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been having issues with a Nether portal - when I build the portal and enter the Nether, everything is fine. The portal is in the right location, I've checked the overworld coordinates, divided them by 8, and they match up to the coordinates in the Nether. Except when I exit the Nether, it takes me to a new portal a distance away. I can use that portal, but it won't let me use the original one - when I try to disable the new portal and use the original, it puts me somewhere different instead. I've had this issue both on the Mushroom Island where I live and another smaller grass island - on the grass island, both attempts of exiting the Nether put me on a platform over the ocean.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do the Y coordinates also line up? If the Nether portal's Y coordinate is too far below or above the overworld portal's Y coordinate, it will still trigger the "can't find portal, search for a new location" code and create a new portal somewhere seemingly random.

Comment: Really? I was given the impression that the Y coords were entirely irrelevant, that it's just the x and z that matter.

Comment: Usually, yes. But the wiki notes: "a portal above Y=128 in the Overworld will generally not be found unless there are no lower portals nearby." Actually, instead of this back-and-forth, could you just edit the coordinates of all three portals into the question? That would make it easier to directly diagnose.

Comment: Y coordinate is factored in as well, portal is searching for a closest target portal by spherical distance, on all axes. As said, can you please add coordinates - 'cause we can't say much without them, it may be a glitch, or it may be working as intended...

Comment: I've tried repeating this on a flat world at normal elevation, 63 I think or something: I built the portal, checked the coords, went into the Nether, checked the coords, it all matched up. Went directly down in the Nether and built a new portal all the way down at lava level. It came out at the same portal, and when I went back in it went up to the original portal, not the one at lava level. So again, I can't see that the y-coord would affect things :/.

Comment: @LeoKing Could you humour us and give us the coords for all three portals anyway? It can't hurt, and it might help. For all *we* know you might have done the math wrong, or there might be some other anomaly you missed that we might catch, but *we* can't answer very well without the numbers. And to be frank, without more details this is just a duplicate of all the other "nether portal is going to the wrong place" questions we get and will get closed as redundant. I'm asking, to give this question a chance, rather than just voting to close as moving on, so please do add detail.

Comment: So I enter the portal at -4149, 69, -50 (xyz), and arrive in the Nether at -520, 68, 5. Then I leave the Nether and arrive in the Overworld at -4149, 64, 46. So about 100 blocks away from the first portal.

Comment: 5 * 8 is a bit more than -50; it's actually quite close to 46

Comment: I have heard that it is something to do with the worlds being different sizes so it doesn't always take you back to where you entered the nether.

Answer (score 2):

The coordinates aren't lining up. You should rebuild your nether-side portal 11 blocks further north at z=-6.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue with one portal that took me into the nether, but the way back brought me to a slightly different location; roughly 50 blocks away from the original portal.

I destroyed the second overworld portal, took off all my gear except for a single pickaxe, went into the nether, destroyed the nether portal there, then jumped into the lava to die and respawn in the overworld. That fixed the problem for me, as the newly created portal worked fine after that.

I'm still not sure what causes it, but my guess is something like a rounding error, where the calculation whether any existing portals are in range, is thrown off, causing the game to spawn a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I've been there.
Just take the coordinates of the portal in the overworld and then go back in the nether and build a portal in those coordinates divided by 8.
It's very important that you dont enter the portal in the overworld until the nether portal is done. So I would recomend you build the overworld portal, light it, BUT DONT ENTER, and then go to the nether through another portal, build the nether portal in the right coordinates, light it, and enter to go to the overworld portal.

I have to add that the y coordinates as said above are also important if the y distance between the overworld portal and the nether one is too big. I had a portal in a flying base with y=165 and couldnt get it to link properly with a portal with y=7 in the nether.

Hope it helps.