# Why does my nether portal reappear in a random area?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Every time I return to the over world through the nether portal, I appear at a random area in the world instead of spawning in the portal I originally used. The coordinates of those places where I end up have no pattern whatsoever.

**Is there a way to fix this issue? Or do I have to delete the world entirely?**

I also did not install any mods, texture packs and this is a Single player world updated to the newest version of Minecraft up to this point in time. In addition, the coordinates in which these portals appear are completely random and ever time I leave the nther, the portal spawns me in some other place.

Comment: This may be a bug if you are playing a snapshot instead of 1.6.4

Comment: Are you actually using the same portal in the Nether?

Comment: Can you give us the coordinates of the netherportal and the different overworld portals?

Comment: Likely it's a coordinates mismatch. The normal portal spawning behaviour can generate a Nether-side portal that won't match the overworld portal that spawned it, creating a one-way link that creates new portals on the return trip. If we have the exact coordinates of both original overworld and Nether portals, we could confirm.

Comment: We're not asking about the coordinates of the new portals. Please, what are the coordinates of the two portals you are expecting should be linking? If you can't clarify that, I'm afraid this is going to be closed, because it's unanswerable otherwise.

Comment: i'm afraid I have already deleted that world and wanted to know how to fix the issue in case such an event shall happen  again

Comment: i have already voted t0o close it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in earlier versions of the game.

An easy way to solve this that I have seen work before is to completely destroy the 'new' portal that appears in the overworld.  Once done, you should be able to enter your portal and exit from the same portal.

To help avoid this, you should also never install a portal in your world in an area that is at all enclosed.  The portal system seems to dislike portals appearing in places they should 'not be' based on the initial construction of the world.

Also avoid dying, as it can cause random nether portals to form in parts of your world.

---

Note this question may be a duplicate of [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126889/nether-portals-exiting-into-a-different-location?rq=1), but since this question never got fully resolved, the two should maybe be merged.

Comment: All of these things (not liking enclosed spaces, dying causing weirdness) I have never heard of. Can you add sources?

Comment: (Also, that other question was resolved exactly. A checkmark isn't necessary for resolution.)

Comment: I saw it on a youtube video actually, which unfortunately I cannot link at the moment.  If you want to look it up, it was made by the ZetaPlays channel, during their initial Nether delve. I apologize for the incompleteness of this answer.

Comment: Those videos seem to be for alpha v1.2.0.  That may have been fixed by now.  I think [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjoqDbVocwo&list=PL59A2B14FFD6DC633&index=43) is the one you were referring to.

Comment: They are somewhat old, so I cannot attest to whether or not this problem has been fixed in later versions of the game.

Comment: That video merely speculates about why the "random" portals happen, it doesn't confirm anything. Portals are since much better understood, and what people thought was "random" was actually quite regular, and is the result of mismatched coordinates.

Comment: I'd suggest putting up your own answer then, to explain the real reason behind this phenomena.  You seem to know the reason for it much better than I do.  Consider this answer deleted as soon as a better one appears.

Comment: @Zibbobz I'm waiting for the asker to respond to the comments on the question. We can't really diagnose this correctly without the portal coordinates.